# Return url from attachment PouchDB

Tags: javascript, promise, couchdb, attachment, pouchdb

I am trying to create a Webpage with CouchDB and PouchDB. At the beginning I created a CouchDB Database ('image'). In this Database is one document with several attachments, all images (.png). I was able to sync the CouchDB database with PouchDB. Now I want to use the attachments stored in PouchDB.

I used the db.get statement to get the attachments.

```
db.get('image', {attachments: true}).then(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc);
});
```

Now I want to get the different images because I need them as src at a different place. At the moment I am using:

```
    db.getAttachment('image', 'image1.png').then(function (blob) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      console.log('URL image1 created');
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('URL image1 not created');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the created url. I guess I have to use return and work with a global variable. But I don't know how to do this in this context.

I used the following [guide](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html) but, as I said, I want to use the url somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part of the solution**

The problem seems to be that the url is generated after the img tag tries to access the url. Which means that even if you are working with global variables you get an error. Therefore I changed the order.

Now the src is updated after the url was generated. The problem is still that it is kind of complicated and not really useful in case you are working with several attachments. I still would prefer to get the url for further use.

```
  <body>

     <img id ="test"  alt="Image from DB" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

  <script>

    var url = " ";

    var imageFW = db.getAttachment('image', 'image1.png');

    imageFW.then(function (blob) {
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
      document.getElementById("test").src = url;
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

  </script>
```

**Update:**
At the end I solved the problem working with promises